# How to perform filter in List Backpack Laravel to relationship column (belongsToMany)

Tags: laravel-backpack

In Tindaklanjut List, I have column USERS that is generated from belongsToMany relationship.

```
CRUD::column([
    'name'         => 'users', // name of relationship method in the model
    'type'         => 'relationship',
    'label'        => 'users', // Table column heading
    // OPTIONAL
    'entity'    => 'users', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model'     => App\Models\User::class, // foreign key model
]);
```

I want to filter the list using  select2_multiple on USER. So the list only shows the data that the selected USERS is in USERS Column. How to do that?

I have tried this, but did not work.

```
CRUD::filter('users')
    ->type('select2_multiple')
    ->values(function () {
        return \App\Models\User::all()->keyBy('id')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
      })
    ->whenActive(function ($values) {
        CRUD::addClause('whereIn', 'users', json_decode($values));
      });
```

This is my Tindaklanjut Model relationship

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'tindaklanjut_user', 'tindaklanjut_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try similar to the following example, I'm doing this way in my project.

```php
$this->crud->addFilter([ // select2_multiple filter
                'name' => 'tags',
                'type' => 'select2_multiple',
                'label' => 'Tags',
            ], function () {
                return \App\Models\ProductTag::all()->keyBy('id')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
            }, function ($values) { // if the filter is active
                $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($values) {
                    foreach (json_decode($values) as $key => $value) {
                        if ($key == 0) {
                            $q->where('product_tags.id', $value);
                        } else {
                            $q->orWhere('product_tags.id', $value);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation.

```
CRUD::filter('users')
    ->type('select2_multiple')
    ->values(function () {
        return \App\Models\User::all()->keyBy('id')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
        })
    ->whenActive(function ($values) {
        foreach (json_decode($values) as $key => $value) {
            $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($value) {
                $query->where('user_id', $value);
            });
                }
        });
```

Comment: can you provide the link where you found this example?

Comment: I found this: [https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-filters#examples-1](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-filters#examples-1)